# Go array slice from function return statement

Tags: return, go, slice

I have the following functions:

```
func (c *Class)A()[4]byte
func B(x []byte)
```

I want to call

```
B(c.A()[:])
```

but I get this error:

```
cannot take the address of c.(*Class).A()
```

How do I properly get a slice of an array returned by a function in Go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of `c.A()`, the return value from a method, is not addressable.

> [Address operators](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Address_operators)
>
> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a
>   pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is,
>   either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation;
>   or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array
>   indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the
>   addressability requirement, x may also be a composite literal.
>
> [Slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)
>
> If the sliced operand is a string or slice, the result of the slice
>   operation is a string or slice of the same type. If the sliced operand
>   is an array, it must be addressable and the result of the slice
>   operation is a slice with the same element type as the array.

Make the value of `c.A()`, an array, addressable for the slice operation `[:]`. For example, assign the value to a variable; a variable is addressable.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Class struct{}

func (c *Class) A() [4]byte { return [4]byte{0, 1, 2, 3} }

func B(x []byte) { fmt.Println("x", x) }

func main() {
    var c Class
    // B(c.A()[:]) // cannot take the address of c.A()
    xa := c.A()
    B(xa[:])
}
```

Output:

```
x [0 1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried sticking the array in a local variable first?

```
ary := c.A()
B(ary[:])
```

Comment: Yes, but when I want to call 20 functions like that, each for a different array length, I have to make a new array for each such call. I hoped there would be a neater solution.

Comment: @ThePiachu: Why are the functions returning an array? Why aren't they returning a slice of the array?

Comment: @peterSO Because the data they return is stored in an object in an array with fixed size. I guess I could also make another functions that would return a slice of an array instead.

Comment: @ThePiachu If you return the array, you will end up copying the entire array for each function.  If you return a slice, the return value will simply copy the slice struct which has a reference to the original array.  For small arrays, not a big deal, but could be expensive.